# Kак правильно записать массив выборки CSV файла?

Tags: python, numpy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать массив выборки CSV файла?

То есть, имеется CSV файл с 500 строками и 18 столбцами.
А для выборки нужны все строки, но определенные столбцы, чтоб построить обучающее дерево.

```
X= np.array([['Class'], ['Price'], ['Age'],[Car]])
```

Если написать в таком стиле, то выдает ошибку, что невозможно провести конвертация из `string` во `float`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [Pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Class', 'Price', 'Age', 'Car']
df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/filename.csv', usecols=cols)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно построить дерево классификации, таком стиле df = pd.read_csv(Location)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
X = np.array([[ ], [ ], [ ], [ ]])
y = np.array([ ])

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=132)
clf.fit(X, y),   т.е имеется 4 признака и одна целевая переменная,  и согласно этим данным построить  дерево.

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите чтобы за вас все сделали от А до Я? :) Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался.